# How to download a file bound to an gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, iframe

I'm missing something simple.

I'm generating some binary files that I'm binding to a GridView.

```
    FileDownloadGrid.DataSource = downloadList;
    FileDownloadGrid.DataBind();
```

The interesting part of the grid is coded like this:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadFile" runat="server" Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadFile1"
           CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FullName") +"|" + Eval("Name") %>'> 
         </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm attempting to do the IFRAME Ajax method to download the file.

```
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
  // Check to be sure this async postback is actually
  //   requesting the file download.
  if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == "FileDownloadGrid") {
    // Create an IFRAME.
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    // Get the desired region from the dropdown.
    var fName = $get("CommandArgument").value;

    // Point the IFRAME to GenerateFile, with the
    //   desired region as a querystring argument.
    iframe.src = "Default2.aspx?fName=" + fName;

    // This makes the IFRAME invisible to the user.
    iframe.style.display = "none";

    // Add the IFRAME to the page.  This will trigger
    //   a request to GenerateFile now.
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
}
```

From what I can found on the web, I can't pickup the CommandArgument client side and I can't seem to figure out how to get the 'FullName' in the script.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I'm pulling my hair out for something that should be pretty simple.

thanks

Gene

Comment: well you could add `data` attribute to your button and retrive the name using jquery. So, you can have an attribute `data-args=<%#Eval("FullName") +"|" + Eval("Name") %>` and use jquery like:  `var fullname = $(#DownloadFile).data['args'];`

Answer (score 0):

After much teeth gnashing, I decided to just call the JavaScript function directly.

here's the javascript:

```
function DownloadFile(filename) {
    // Check to be sure this async postback is actually
    // Create an IFRAME.

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    // Point the IFRAME to GenerateFile, with the
    //   desired region as a querystring argument.
    iframe.src = "Default2.aspx?fileName=" + filename;

    // This makes the IFRAME invisible to the user.
    iframe.style.display = "none";

    // Add the IFRAME to the page.  This will trigger
    //   a request to GenerateFile now.
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

here is the code that worked for me:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadFile" runat="server" Text="Download"  
   onClientClick='<%# string.Format("DownloadFile(\"{0}\");", Eval("FullName")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

A key bit seemed to be converting the 'FullName' path from having \ to /.

```
      string serverPath = toFileName.Replace("\\", "/");
```

then in default2.aspx.cs I do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string workPath = Request.QueryString["fileName"];
  string fullPath = workPath.Replace('/', '\\');
  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
  string attachmentHeader = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName);
  Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", attachmentHeader);
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.WriteFile(fullPath);
  Response.End();
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do all these, but this is what I came up with by hacking around and I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: go ahead and mark this answer as accepted. [this is perfectly acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)